# How to add id dynamically to each blue circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

An example can be found at    [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avinash9044001/52na92n2/)
Add ids to these svg object during creating creation.

```
r.circle(xEnd, yEnd,8).attr({
               "fill": "blue",
               "stroke": "#000",
               "stroke-width": "3"
            }).click(function(){
               //alert("i am clicked");
    active = this,
    this.attr({fill : "blue"})
    this.animate({"stroke-width": "5",'r':'5'},1000,"elastic");
   //$('#example').popover();
  }).hover(function(){
      //alert("i am hoved");
    this.attr({fill : "green"})
    this.animate({"stroke-width": "5",'r':'20'},1000,"elastic");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add an `id` attr like that

```
this.attr({'id' : "your-id"})
```

Comment: Sir, during the click i will be triggering another event based on it's id. These ids have to be allocated during the svg creation. so "this." won't work

Comment: which dom element you want to add id?